# Using Java Deflater/Inflater with custom dictionary causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, compression, zip, deflate

The following code is based on the example given in the [javadocs for java.util.zip.Deflater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html).  The only changes I have made is to create a byte array called dict and then set the dictionary on both the Deflater and Inflater instances using the setDictionary(byte[]) method.

The problem I'm seeing is that when I call Inflater.setDictionary() with the exact same array as I used for the Deflater, I get an IllegalArgumentException.

Here is the code in question:

```
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class DeflateWithDictionary {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputString = "blahblahblahblahblah??";
        byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] dict = "blah".getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Compress the bytes
        byte[] output = new byte[100];
        Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
        compresser.setInput(input);
        compresser.setDictionary(dict);
        compresser.finish();
        int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);

        // Decompress the bytes
        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
        decompresser.setInput(output, 0, compressedDataLength);
        decompresser.setDictionary(dict);  //IllegalArgumentExeption thrown here
        byte[] result = new byte[100];
        int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
        decompresser.end();

        // Decode the bytes into a String
        String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Decompressed String: " + outputString);
    }
}
```

If I try deflating the same compressed bytes without setting the dictionary, I get no error but the result returned is zero bytes.

Is there anything special I need to do in order to use a custom dictionary with Deflater/Inflater?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually figured this out while formulating the question but thought I should post the question anyway so others might benefit from my struggles.

It turns out you have to call inflate() once after setting the input but *before* setting the dictionary.  The value returned will be 0, and a call to needsDictionary() will then return true.  After that you can set the dictionary and call inflate again.

The amended code is as follows:

```
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class DeflateWithDictionary {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputString = "blahblahblahblahblah??";
        byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] dict = "blah".getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Compress the bytes
        byte[] output = new byte[100];
        Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
        compresser.setInput(input);
        compresser.setDictionary(dict);
        compresser.finish();
        int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);

        // Decompress the bytes
        Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
        decompresser.setInput(output, 0, compressedDataLength);
        byte[] result = new byte[100];
        decompresser.inflate(result);
        decompresser.setDictionary(dict);
        int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
        decompresser.end();

        // Decode the bytes into a String
        String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Decompressed String: " + outputString);
    }
}
```

This seems very counter intuitive and clunky from an API design perspective, so please enlighten me if there are any better alternatives.

Comment: The reason for the `needsDictionary()` is that the zlib format allows the use of different dictionaries in the same application, and indicates in the file header the dictionary's Adler32-checksum. To read this header (and allow the application on the decompressing side to choose the right dictionary), a first call of `inflate` is needed.

Comment: When I did this, I needed to set the dictionary before inflate() which inquisitively makes sense. So something is amiss in your example...