# SetDictionary Method of Deflater Class

Tags: java, compression

I'm new to Java and trying to understand how dictionary in compression works.

[`public void setDictionary(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#setDictionary%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Can Anyone give me an example of how to use this method?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem to solve?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655740/using-java-deflater-inflater-with-custom-dictionary-causes-illegalargumentexcept

Comment: And this one, too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011653/how-to-find-a-good-optimal-dictionary-for-zlib-setdictionary-when-processing-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dictionary" you mentioned is not specific to Java itself, but is part of the DEFLATE compression algorithm. You can find a lot of references on the Internet describing the algorithm; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) is a good starting point.