# What's wrong with this use of java Deflater/Inflater with a dictionary

Tags: java, zlib

I'm trying to use `Inflater` and `Deflater` with a dictionary but it's not working. When I run this simple test program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class DictTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final int level = 9;
        final boolean nowrap = true;

        // compress
        final Deflater def = new Deflater(level, nowrap);
        final byte[] abcd = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44 };
        def.setDictionary(abcd);
        def.setInput(abcd);
        def.finish();
        final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        final int nbytes = def.deflate(buf);
        assert def.finished();
        def.end();

        // decompress
        final Inflater inf = new Inflater(nowrap);
        inf.setInput(buf, 0, nbytes + 1);       // include extra "dummy" byte
        while (true) {
            while (inf.inflate(buf) != 0) {
                // discard
            }
            assert !inf.needsInput();
            if (inf.finished())
                break;
            assert inf.needsDictionary();
            inf.setDictionary(abcd);
            continue;
        }
        inf.end();
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
$ javac DictTest.java && java -ea DictTest
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:280)
    at DictTest.main(DictTest.java:27)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using streams - I'm using Deflater/Inflater directly because this is required in order to use a dictionary. Both ZIP and GZIP are based on the same zlib 'deflate' algorithm, which is a variation of LZ77. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib#Algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the inflater dictionary before you set input. Also, your infinite loop will run (forever). You wanted something like

```
final int level = 9;
final boolean nowrap = true;

// compress
final Deflater def = new Deflater(level, nowrap);
final byte[] abcd = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44 };
def.setDictionary(abcd);
def.setInput(abcd);
def.finish();
final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
final int nbytes = def.deflate(buf);
assert def.finished();
def.end();

// decompress
final Inflater inf = new Inflater(nowrap);
inf.setDictionary(abcd);
inf.setInput(buf); // include extra "dummy" byte
while (inf.inflate(buf) != 0) {
    // discard
}
assert !inf.needsInput();
assert inf.needsDictionary();
inf.end();
```

And it then runs without error here.

Comment: Thanks, but that's weird. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655740/using-java-deflater-inflater-with-custom-dictionary-causes-illegalargumentexcept you have to set the dictionary after calling inflate() and getting back needsDictionary() == true.

Comment: You are using a static dictionary. Read the comment in that linked answer.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why, in the original code, does inflate() throw an exception instead of returning zero and asking for a dictionary (via needsDictionary() returning true)? In other words, suppose the decompression code did not know ahead of time whether any dictionary was used for compression, or if so which one. Then how would you write the decompression code to handle all possible cases?